# Align controls in navbar Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 in my web application , and  below html produces the layout depicated in the image

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']" routerLinkActive="active" >Books & NoteBooks</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ><a [routerLink]="['']">Home</a></li>      

      <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <a [routerLink]="['./acategories' ,category.name , 'products']" routerLinkActive="active">{{category.name}}</a>
      </li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['./acart']" routerLinkActive="active">
      <span *ngIf="cartCount > 0" class="badge">{{cartCount}}</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">&nbsp;Bag</span></a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['./aorders']" routerLinkActive="active">Order Details</a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['./about']" routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
      <li>&nbsp;>&nbsp;>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>  

    <form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="onSearch()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
          <div class="input-group">    
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Item Name">      
          </div>
        </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search"/>
      </form><br>

  </div>
```

[image]

Now I would like to have text box and search button vertical aligned middle  , any idea what needs to be modified.

Comment: add a **class = "align-middle"** in your form , or else you can write custom inline css  **vertical-align : middle**, let me know if any of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`. Check out working solution [here jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wederonaqu/1/edit?output)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the .navbar-form class along with the .form-inline class as:

```
<form class="form-inline navbar-form" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSearch()">
        <div class="form-group">...
```

After this, maybe you can get rid of the `<br>` tag after the form closing tag.
Also, if you want to align the Search box and button to the right corner, you can use .navbar-right as well:

```
<form class="form-inline navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSearch()">
        <div class="form-group">...
```